# Can not determine type information for -[GSMutableString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: withString:]

Tags: objective-c

I have a strange issue (only on windows, it works fine on mac).
I want to remove blank spaces, (so to replace them with an empty string), and I have the error above when I come to this part of code:

```
NSString *theReport = [theTemplate report];
theReport = [theReport stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""];
```

[theTemplateReport] return itsReport, which is a NSString.
I don't understand the part about MutableString in the error.
Does anyone have a clue ?
Thank you !

Comment: NSMutableString *theReport = [theTemplate report]; use this.

Comment: Try using that function instead: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablestring/1412453-replaceoccurrencesofstring?language=objc

Comment: Apparently `[theTemplate report]` returns `GSMutableString` and  `GSMutableString` ≠ `NSMutableString` and isn't a subclass of `NSString`.

Comment: @vitormm I tried :     NSMutableString *theReport = [[[theTemplate report ]mutableCopy]autorelease];

    theReport = [theReport replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theReport length])];  but that leads to a crash of the application